# RegExp for parsing a Math Expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, math, string-parsing

Hey I've written a fractal-generating program in JavaScript and HTML5 ([here's the link](http://fractal.nodejitsu.com)), which was about a 2 year process including all the research I did on Complex math and fractal equations, and I was looking to update the interface, since it is quite intimidating for people to look at. While looking through the code I noticed that some of my old techniques for going about doing things were very inefficient, such as my [Complex.parseFunction](https://github.com/patrickroberts/Javascript-Complex-Math-Library).

I'm looking for a way to use RegExp to parse components of the expression such as functions, operators, and variables, as well as implementing the proper order of operations for the expression. An example below might demonstrate what I mean:

```
//the first example parses an expression with two variables and outputs to string
console.log(Complex.parseFunction("i*-sinh(C-Z^2)", ["Z","C"], false))

"Complex.I.mult(Complex.neg(Complex.sinh(C.sub(Z.cPow(new Complex(2,0,2,0))))))"

//the second example parses the same expression but outputs to function
console.log(Complex.parseFunction("i*-sinh(C-Z^2)", ["Z","C"], true))

function(Z,C){
  return Complex.I.mult(Complex.neg(Complex.sinh(C.sub(Z.cPow(new Complex(2,0,2,0))))));
}
```

I know how to handle RegExp using `String.prototype.replace` and all that, all I need is the RegExp itself. Please note that it should be able to tell the difference between the subtraction operator (e.g. "C-Z^2") and the negative function (e.g. "i*-(Z^2+C)") by noting whether it is directly after a variable or an operator respectively.

Comment: My recommendation would be to not use regex for something like this. Regex for problems like this (if even possible) have to be extremely complex, are very hard to read and maintain, and can even perform worse than other parsing methods. You may want to use regex for parsing small pieces of the string which are already known to serve a specific role, but a regex for such a generic and comprehensive situation is, in my experience, usually not the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can use regular expressions as part of an expression parser, for example to break out tokens, regular expressions do not have the computational power to parse properly nested mathematical expressions.  That is essentially one of the core results of computing theory (finite state automata vs. push down automata).   You probably want to look at something like recursive-descent or LR parsing.

I also wouldn't worry too much about the efficiency of parsing an expression provided you only do it once.  Given all of the other math you are doing, I doubt it is material.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on LR parsing? I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: It is just a method of generating parsers.  There may even be tools available for generating the code from a description of your expression syntax.  Certainly are for many other languages but I don't know of one for javascript offhand.   If writing your own, start with recursive descent - it is easier to understand.  Typically this stuff is covered in books on compilers or language theory.

Comment: I have never tried using this, but a quick search for a Javascript parser generator yielded this: http://pegjs.majda.cz/. With any decent parser generator and a couple examples, it shouldn't be too tough to make a parser for arithmetic expressions

Comment: Thanks for the help. Didn't realize that RegExp wasn't good for nested parsing.